# conan: what is the difference between specifing compiler in env or in settings

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, conan

This was my conan (1.59) profile:

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=14
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

Which didn't work because cmake detected not clang but /usr/bin/c++

```
-- Conan toolchain: Setting CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON (options.fPIC)
-- Conan toolchain: Setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = OFF
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/c++"
```

I then added the environment options for clang environment which resulted in this:

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=clang
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=14
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

And voila it builds.

But now I don't understand what the compiler and compiler.version settings are actually good for. My initial thought was that those values define what is written into the conan toolchain file which is then invoked by cmake. Looking into it though I can only see the compiler flags specified, not the actual CC and CXX compiler paths. So I was wrong about that and it appears that conan communicate the compiler to cmake only via environmetal variables. If so what are the `compiler` and `compiler.version` settings good for? How is it used by conan?

Comment: There are missing information, which Conan version are you using? Which Conan generator did you use? It seems like you forgot to pass `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`. I suggest you reading the tutorial with CMake first: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Comment: @uilianries I'm using conan 1.59. I didn't invoke cmake, this is the cmake output from a dependency invoked by conan itself using `conan install .. --build missing` It did specify the conan_toolchain.cmake though.

Comment: About env vs settings: Using env is unsafe, as it does not affect your package ID, so always prefer settings, otherwise, you will package something, but the package will another information. You don't need to specify the compiler path, in case it's the default already, but in case you want be explicit, use the config `tools.build.compiler_executables`, it will pass to cmake automatically the compiler path: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/global_conf.html

Comment: could you please say which dependency are you trying to build? Is it an official Conan package? Are you trying to install directly from Conan Center? If it's a local recipe instead, could you share the recipe?

Comment: @uilianries: Yes it's the official gdal package from conancenter. I'm using --build missing which i suppose downloads directly from conancenter/github. It's not a local recipe. I would like to understand the mechanism more in which conan forwards the specified compiler to cmake?

Comment: Conan will not configure automatically the compiler, unless you configure to do it. You should add `[conf]` entry to your profile and set `tools.build:compiler_executables={"c": "/usr/bin/clang", "cxx": "/usr/bin/clang++"}`, then Conan should pass it to cmake automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The `settings` are a declaration of the current binary specification. It assumes that the environment is configured to use those settings. Settings are used:

- In recipes, with comparisons like `if self.settings.compiler == "gcc": ...`
- To compute the `package_id` of the binaries.
- It is listed in `conan list ...` commands

Settings do not configure, activate or define what compilers to use for example, in all situations. CMake integrations might be smart enough to do it automatically, but other integrations like autotools might require further configuration, like settings CC/CXX environment variables.

On the other hand, environment definition like `[env]` is setting environment variables, and setting environment variables like `CC/CXX` can actually configure one compiler or other.

The profiles should be consistent, the declared `settings` should match whatever is defined in environment variables.

Comment: Good answer thank you. Is CMake smart enough though? It always worked for me out of the box until recently at work. So are environment variables the only way that the toolchain is propagated to cmake? I thought that CMakeDeps generator from conan will generate the files necessary for cmake, but it appears that compilers are left out?

Comment: CMake is enough in many scenarios, but not all. It depends on the generator, for example ``Visual Studio`` generators might not need any environment, as CMake knows how to set the VS prompt (vcvars), but using other generators like ``Ninja`` might require setting the environment yourself (our using Conan generated ``conanvcvars.bat``, which is automatically generated and included in ``conanbuild.bat`` if necessary)